# EF Linq Contains with many to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new in LINQ. I've written this code:

```
 public IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments(string searchParam, int displayStart, int displayLenght, int sortColumnIndex, string searchDir, out int filteredDataCount, out int allDataCount)
        {
            using(var _db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var documents = _db.Documents.Where(x=>x.Deleted == null).Include(x=>x.VacationTypes);
                allDataCount = documents.Count();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParam))
                {
                    documents = documents.Where(d => d.DocumentName.Contains(searchParam) || 
                        d.VacationTypes.Any(x=>x.Type.Contains(searchParam))).OrderBy(x=>x.DocumentName).ThenByDescending(d=>d.UploadDate);                    
                }
                filteredDataCount = documents.Count();
                if(sortColumnIndex == 0)
                {
                    switch (searchDir)
                    {
                        case "asc":
                            documents = documents.OrderBy(x => x.FileType).ThenByDescending(x => x.UploadDate).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLenght);
                            break;
                        case "desc":
                            documents = documents.OrderByDescending(x => x.FileType).ThenByDescending(x => x.UploadDate).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLenght);
                            break;
                    }

                }
                else if(sortColumnIndex == 1)
                {
                    switch (searchDir)
                    {
                        case "asc":
                            documents = documents.OrderBy(x => x.DocumentName).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLenght);
                            break;
                        case "desc":
                            documents = documents.OrderByDescending(x => x.DocumentName).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLenght);
                            break;
                    }

                }
                else if(sortColumnIndex == 2)
                {
                    switch(searchDir)
                    {
                        case "asc":
                            documents = documents.OrderByDescending(x => x.UploadDate).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLenght);
                            break;
                        case "desc":
                            documents = documents.OrderBy(x => x.UploadDate).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLenght);
                            break;
                    }
                }                
                return documents.ToList();
            }
        }
```

As you see, I need to filtering data by `DocumentName` and by `VacationType`. Documents has `many-to-many` relation with `VacationTypes`. VacationTypes has field `Type`. I need filtering by this field.
Question: Is my code possible? Can anyone provide better solution?

Comment: what do you mean by "Is my code possible?", if it working or not , from my point of view it will work with your case, are you getting any errors?

Comment: It works. But I wanna to know professionals opinion.

Comment: You should add the code where you materialize the query. ie what are you doing with the documents collection you retrieve? Furthermore you dont need the include if its only used in the where and why only sort when there is a searchparam?

Comment: I need Include, because I'm using collection of VacationTypes after DB connection closed.

Comment: The only strange thing I see is the ordering which is done only when there's a search param. I would do a `documents = documents.OrderBy(xxx)` after the test.

Comment: It's ok, I've implemented sorting logic now.

Comment: please post your answer